# Reference the last column / row in an org-mode table

Tags: org-mode, org-table, spreadsheet

**The Situation:** I read the [Org Spreadsheet tutorial](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-spreadsheet-intro.html) but couldn't find an answer.  Commonly, I want to have the result of a formula in the *last* row of a table, i.e., have something like

```
#+TBLFM: @LAST$2=somefunction(...)
```

This means that in the formula, I will have to do something like `vmean(@2..@LASTBUTONE)`

**The Problem:** Now, this becomes tiring when adding new rows above the last one, because it means I'll have to remember to change the row references.

**My Question:** Is there a way to reference the *last* or *last-but-one* row in a way that doesn't break when adding rows above the last one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two notes to answer your questions.

The first answers your question directly. Take a look at The Org Manual and its section on [References](https://orgmode.org/manual/References.html#References).

In short: use `@>` to refer to the last row.

The example provided in the manual says:

> `@>$5` [refers to the] field in the last row, in column 5

Referring to the last-to-one row is not possible in this way, as far as I know (but I'd love to be corrected - edit: and I have been, see below).
There are, however, many other ways to refer to cells in the table.

My second suggestion is to remember to use the `org` functions when inserting rows (rather than, for example, copy pasting). The functions are smart and will update the coordinates in your formulas, even when referenced through absolute numbers.

So use `org-table-insert-column` and `org-table-insert-row` when adding to your your spreadsheet.

The same goes for shifting rows and columns: use the built in `org` keybindings and formulas will be updated.

---

**UPDATE**: Thanks to @NickD for pointing out that `@>>` can be used to refer to the second to last row. Works for colmuns as well.

From the manual:

> `$<` and `$>` are immutable references to the first and last column, respectively, and you can use `$>>>` to indicate the third column from the right.

Comment: "Referring to the last-to-one row is not possible in this way": it most certainly is: `@>>` is the last-but-one row, `@>>>` is the last-but-two, etc. Similarly for columns: `$>` is the last column, `$>>` is the last-but-one etc. See [Field references](https://orgmode.org/manual/References.html#References).

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks. I'll update my answer as well.

Comment: Also @-1 and $-1 refer to the second-to-last, @-2, etc.

Comment: @mankoff I don't think that's entirely correct. The `-1` and `-2` are relative to the current position, according to the manual, and are useful when entering a formula straight into a field with `:=`.

Comment: @EFLS correct... But when entering a formula not in a field (but at `+#TBLFM:`, what do you use to sum columns into the last element? It could be `@>=vsum(@1..@>>)` or `@>=vsum(@1..@-1)`. I've been using the latter, where the `@-1` means 'The second-to-last row'.

Comment: @mankoff Ah, thanks. Didn't know that, now the way it is worded in the manual makes more sense.